# proof of invertible linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T \colon V \to V$ is an invertible linear transformation and $W ⊆ V$ is a subspace such that $T(w)∈W$ for all $w∈W$, then, for all $w∈W$, $T^{−1}(w)∈W$.

To prove this statement, I want take a $w∈W$ firstly, then $v =T(w)∈W$. Since $T$ is invertible, $T^{−1}(v) = w∈W$.

But now I found that in this way $v\neq w$, so it seems I cannot get the same conclusion with the statement? I'm not sure if this is right. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Is your vector space $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: The statement didn't mention this. I think we can assume it's finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $T'\colon W\to W$, the map induced by $T$. This is linear and injective. What can you conclude (assuming $V$ is finite dimensional)?

The statement is false if $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Consider the vector space $V$ having a basis $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ indexed by the integers. Define the linear map $T\colon V\to V$ by
$$
T(x_n)=x_{n+1}
$$
and define $W$ as the span of $\{x_n:n>0\}$. Then clearly $T$ is invertible, $T(W)\subseteq W$, $x_1\in W$, but $T^{-1}(x_1)=x_0\notin W$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite catch you. $T'$ is injective, so $dim{ket(T')} = 0$. But it seems we cannot conclude $T'$ is not surjective?

Comment: @leaf If $V$ is finite dimensional, so is $W$; hence $T'$ is surjective. Now you should be able to finish.

Comment: $@egreg$ Thank you, I think I got it. And for my proof, is it wrong because V may not be finite dimensional?

Comment: @leaf No, it's wrong because it proves nothing at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: $@egreg$ Ok I'll try to fix it. Thank you

Comment: @leaf I added an example where the statement fails for an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: $@egreg$ I got it!